# Cannot set GS register in Protected Mode

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader, osdev

I am writing an operating system based on the information from the [OSDev Wiki](http://www.osdev.org/) and some related books. I found that after jumping into Protected Mode, the segment initialization routine was not properly executed. Here is my second stage loader and kernel code:

```
; stage2
; still -f bin
[org 0xd200] ; calculated by first stage loader

; GDTs are defined here
jmp entry

GDT_DESC_START:

GDT0:
dw 0 ; Limit 0~15
dw 0 ; Base 0~15
db 0 ; Base 16~23
db 0 ; Access Byte
db 0 ; Limit 16~19 + Flags
db 0 ; Base 24~31

DESCRIPTOR_CODE:
dw 0xffff ; Limit 0~15
CODE_BASE_AX dw 0 ; Base 0~15
CODE_BASE_EAHL db 0 ; Base 16~23
db 0x9a ; 1001 1011 - Vaild, ring 0, executable, strict, readable,
; accessed
db 0x9f; 1100 1111 - paging, 32-bit
CODE_BASE_EAHH db 0 ; Base 24~31

DESCRIPTOR_DATA: 
dw 0xffff ; Limit 0~15
dw 0x0000 ; Base 0~15
db 0x00 ; Base 16~23
db 0x92 ; 1001 0011 - vaild, ring 0, data, forward, writable, accessed
db 0x9F ; 1100 1111 - 4KB, 32-bits
db 0x0 ; Base 24~31

; Note that in further development, VRAM descriptor should be
; created dynamically
; Base = 0x000b8000
DESCRIPTOR_VIDEO:
dw 0xffff
dw 0x8000
db 0x0b
db 0x92
db 0x4F
db 0x00

GDT_DESC_END:

GDTR0:
        dw GDT_DESC_END - GDT_DESC_START - 1
        dd GDT_DESC_START

SELECTOR_CODE equ DESCRIPTOR_CODE - GDT0
SELECTOR_DATA equ DESCRIPTOR_DATA - GDT0
SELECTOR_VIDEO equ DESCRIPTOR_VIDEO - GDT0

; --- code ------------

[bits 16]

entry:

cli
; open a20 gate
in al, 0x92
or al, 0x02
and al, ~1
out 0x92, al
; goto protected mode
; rewrite code descriptor
xor eax, eax
mov eax, entry_32
mov [CODE_BASE_AX], ax
shr eax, 16
mov [CODE_BASE_EAHH], ah
mov [CODE_BASE_EAHL], al
; load the gdt
lgdt [GDTR0]
mov eax, cr0
or eax, 1
mov cr0, eax
jmp dword SELECTOR_CODE:0 ; -> protected mode!!!

[bits 32]
entry_32:
mov ax, SELECTOR_DATA
mov ds, ax
mov ss, ax
mov ax, SELECTOR_VIDEO
mov gs, ax

; print a 'P'
xor ax, ax
mov edi, 0
mov ah, 0x07
mov al, 'P'
mov [gs:edi], ax

.sleep:
        hlt
        jmp .sleep
```

The `P` was not printed on the screen and I found out that `GS=0` rather than `GS=0x18`. The `P` was written to the linear address `0x0`. Strangely, the `HLT` loop works normally. I am new to x86 assembly so I couldn't figure out where the problem was. What is wrong with the code? How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Potential Bugs

I believe most of your problems stem from issues with the flags in some of your [GDT descriptors](http://wiki.osdev.org/Global_Descriptor_Table). In the CODE descriptor table you have:

```
db 0x9a ; 1001 1011 - Vaild, ring 0, executable, strict, readable,
db 0x9f ; 1100 1111 - paging, 32-bit
```

It should have been:

```
db 0x9a ; 1001 1010 - Valid, ring 0, executable, strict, readable,
db 0xcf ; 1100 1111 - paging, 32-bit
```

In particular `1100 1111` is `0xcf`, not `0x9f`. You could have also defined the *DB*s with binary values like:

```
db 10011010b  ; Valid, ring 0, executable, strict, readable,
db 11001111b  ; paging, 32-bit
```

By doing it this way with binary values makes it less error prone and a bit more readable.

In the DATA descriptor you had:

```
db 0x92 ; 1001 0011 - vaild, ring 0, data, forward, writable, accessed
db 0x9F ; 1100 1111 - 4KB, 32-bits
```

I believe it should have been:

```
db 10010010b  ; valid, ring 0, data, forward, writable, accessed
db 11001111b  ; 4KB, 32-bits
```

Your `0x9F` should have been `0xCF` (11001111)

---

### Other Considerations

It is a good idea to set up *SS*:*ESP* after entering protected mode. Code like this would work:

```
mov es, ax                       ; Set ES as well
mov ss, ax
mov esp,0x90000                  ; We should specify a stack pointer
cld                              ; Set direction flag forward
```

`0x90000` can be any valid linear address. Since some instructions like [*MOVSB*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVS:MOVSB:MOVSW:MOVSD:MOVSQ.html) need *ES* being set, it is a good idea to have *ES*=*DS*. If you use any of the instructions that require a direction flag it is a good idea to explicitly set it. Most code assumes forward movement that can be set using the [*CLD*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CLD.html) instruction.

As an experiment you can add this code to display a string from memory. This will test that the offsets generated for *DS* work as expected; and tests if the *GS* segment points to the base of the color text video memory at 0xb8000.

```
; print "Hello, World!"
xor ax, ax
mov edi, 0
mov ecx, 0
mov ah, 0x07

; Display a nul terminated string from a variable to video memory
; using a character attribute in AH
strloop:
mov al, [mystr+ecx]
test al,al
je .endstrloop
mov [gs:edi+ecx*2], ax
inc ecx
jmp strloop
.endstrloop:
```

---

### Revised Code

The revised stage2 code could look like this:

```
; stage2
; still -f bin
[org 0xd200] ; calculated by first stage loader

; GDTs are defined here
jmp entry

GDT_DESC_START:

GDT0:
dw 0 ; Limit 0~15
dw 0 ; Base 0~15
db 0 ; Base 16~23
db 0 ; Access Byte
db 0 ; Limit 16~19 + Flags
db 0 ; Base 24~31

DESCRIPTOR_CODE:
dw 0xffff ; Limit 0~15
CODE_BASE_AX dw 0 ; Base 0~15
CODE_BASE_EAHL db 0 ; Base 16~23
db 10011010b ; Valid, ring 0, executable, strict, readable,
; accessed
db 11001111b ; paging, 32-bit
CODE_BASE_EAHH db 0 ; Base 24~31

DESCRIPTOR_DATA:
dw 0xffff ; Limit 0~15
dw 0x0000 ; Base 0~15
db 0x00 ; Base 16~23
db 10010010b ; valid, ring 0, data, forward, writable, accessed
db 11001111b ; 4KB, 32-bits
db 0x0 ; Base 24~31

; Note that in further development, VRAM descriptor should be
; created dynamically
; Base = 0x000b8000
DESCRIPTOR_VIDEO:
dw 0xffff
dw 0x8000
db 0x0b
db 0x92
db 0x4F
db 0x00

GDT_DESC_END:

GDTR0:
        dw GDT_DESC_END - GDT_DESC_START - 1
        dd GDT_DESC_START

SELECTOR_CODE equ DESCRIPTOR_CODE - GDT0
SELECTOR_DATA equ DESCRIPTOR_DATA - GDT0
SELECTOR_VIDEO equ DESCRIPTOR_VIDEO - GDT0

; --- code ------------

[bits 16]

entry:

cli
; open a20 gate
in al, 0x92
or al, 0x02
and al, ~1
out 0x92, al

; goto protected mode
; rewrite code descriptor
xor eax, eax
mov eax, entry_32
mov [CODE_BASE_AX], ax
shr eax, 16
mov [CODE_BASE_EAHH], ah
mov [CODE_BASE_EAHL], al

; load the gdt
lgdt [GDTR0]
mov eax, cr0
or eax, 1
mov cr0, eax
jmp dword SELECTOR_CODE:0x0      ; -> protected mode!!!

[bits 32]
entry_32:

mov ax, SELECTOR_DATA
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax                       ; Set ES as well
mov ss, ax
mov esp,0x90000                  ; We should specify a stack pointer
mov ax, SELECTOR_VIDEO
mov gs, ax
cld                              ; Set direction flag forward

; print "Hello, World!"
xor ax, ax
mov edi, 0
mov ecx, 0
mov ah, 0x07

; Display a nul terminated string from a variable to video memory
; using a character attribute in AH
strloop:
mov al, [mystr+ecx]
test al,al
je .endstrloop
mov [gs:edi+ecx*2], ax
inc ecx
jmp strloop
.endstrloop:

.sleep:
        hlt
        jmp .sleep

mystr: db "Hello, World!",0
```

Although your question doesn't have a first stage, I provide a simplistic one for readers who may wish to test:

```
[BITS 16]
org 0x7C00

        STAGE2OFFSET equ 0xd200

start:
        ; This section of code is added based on Michael Petch's bootloader tips
        ; See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32705076/3857942
        xor ax,ax          ; We want a segment of 0 for DS for this question
        mov ds,ax          ;     Set AX to appropriate segment value for your situation
        mov es,ax          ; In this case we'll default to ES=DS
        mov bx,0x7c00      ; Stack segment can be any usable memory

        cli                ; Disable interrupts to circumvent bug on early 8088 CPUs
        mov ss,ax      
        mov sp,bx          ; This places top of the stack @ 0x0000:0x7c00
                           ;    just below the bootsector.
        sti                ; Re-enable interrupts
        cld                ; Set the direction flag to be positive direction

        mov ah, 0x02       ; Read sectors from drive
        mov al, 4          ; Read 4 sectors
        mov ch, 0          ; Cylinder 0
        mov cl, 2          ; Sector 2
        mov dh, 0          ; Head 0
        xor bx, bx
        mov es, bx
        mov bx, STAGE2OFFSET    ; ES:BX = 0x0000:0xd200 (start of memory to read into)
        int 0x13

        jmp 0x0000:STAGE2OFFSET ; Far Jump to second stage. Sets CS=0

times   510-($-$$) db 0         ; Create padding to fill out to 510 bytes
dw      0xaa55                  ; Magic number in the trailer of a boot sector
```

These files could be assembled and built into a disk image with these commands:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=floppy.img bs=1024 count=1440
nasm -f bin bootload.asm -o bootload.bin
nasm -f bin stage2.asm -o stage2.bin

dd if=bootload.bin of=floppy.img conv=notrunc
dd if=stage2.bin of=floppy.img bs=512 seek=1 conv=notrunc
```

---

### Code Segment Recommendation

Although the way you set up your CODE descriptor will work, another alternative would have been to use a base of zero. This can be accomplished by:

- **remove** these lines:

> ```
> ; rewrite code descriptor
> xor eax, eax
> mov eax, entry_32
> mov [CODE_BASE_AX], ax
> shr eax, 16
> mov [CODE_BASE_EAHH], ah
> mov [CODE_BASE_EAHL], al
> ```

- Modify the *ptr16:32 FAR JMP* to use the offset of `entry_32`:

> ```
> jmp dword SELECTOR_CODE:entry_32 ; -> protected mode!!!
> ```

Rather than a 0 offset and a non zero descriptor base, we simply use a descriptor base of 0. We can then use the offset of the label `entry_32` for the [ptr16:32 *FAR JMP*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/JMP.html). By keeping *CS*=*DS*=*ES*=*SS* you simplify the code by using a 4gb linear address space starting at 0. Keeping it consistent may avoid potential coding bugs in the future.

Answer (score 1):

From the code, I see you have:

```
SELECTOR_CODE equ DESCRIPTOR_CODE - GDT0
```

This gives the "length" of the GDT0. Then you call

```
jmp dword SELECTOR_CODE:0 ; -> protected mode!!!
```

Not sure what your intention is, but I don't think that is jumping where you intend. Where do you want to jump?

Comment: This was probably better asked in a comment than an answer. `SELECTOR_CODE equ DESCRIPTOR_CODE - GDT0` is correct. It defines the code selector based on the distance of DESCRIPTOR_CODE from GDT0. The is appropriate for descriptors. I haven't had a chance to look at the correctness of the code but I can say that he has attempted to dynamically create the CODE descriptor to start with a base of `entry_32` rather than 0. In theory if everything is set right `jmp dword SELECTOR_CODE:0` would jump to 0x08:0x00000000. Since the base of the descriptor is `entry_32` it should jump to `entry_32:`

Comment: This actually works because a ring 0 GDT selector happens to have the same value as its offset in the GDT.  Bits 0 and 1 of a selector are the requested privilege level (RPL), and bit 2 is clear for GDT selectors, and set for LDT selectors. Bits 3-15 are the index in to the GDT/LDT.  Since GDT/LDT entries are 8 bytes long, this means the second GDT entry is at offset 8, while its selector value is also 8 (index 1, GDT selector, RPL 0).